# When making a Leaflet map,how can pull and convert the GeoJSON coordinates to a latLng?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gis, geojson, qgis

I'm making a map using **Leaflet**, and populating the map with data from a GeoJSON file. I want to use the `distanceTo` function, but it requires a `latLng` object. Is there a way to `convert` the GeoJSON's `properties.geometry.coordinates` into `latLng`?

I have an array of 31 coordinates, from using the `push()` method on the `onEachLayer`:

```
var coords = [];

onEachFeature : function(feature,layer) {
 coords.push(feature.geometry.coordinates)
 //console.log(coords)...
```

After running that, the coords array is populated with the array for each coordinate. Is there a way to 'convert' this array of arrays to a `latLng` object so `ditanceTo` can be used?

End goal is to run the `latLng` objects through a loop using `distanceTo`, so that each popup displays the distance from the center point.

```
     var low = L.geoJson(hosp, {    
     pointToLayer: function(feature,latlng) {
      return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
            color: 'yellow',
             weight: 2,
             fillColor: 'green',
             fillOpacity: .7,
             radius:9

         });
     },

     filter: function (feature, layer) {
         if(feature.properties.DAILY_PAT <= '600'){
             return feature;}
     },


   onEachFeature : function(feature,layer) {
     coords.push(feature.geometry.coordinates)
     //console.log(coords)

     layer.on('click',function(){

       layer.bindPopup("<b>Low Enrollement </b><br>"+"<b>School Name: </b>" 
           + feature.properties.FACILITY_N+"<br><b># of Students: </b>"
           + feature.properties.DAILY_PAT).openPopup()
       });  
     }
    }).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create the coordinates array with Leaflet's `LatLng` object?

```
var coords = [];

onEachFeature : function(feature,layer) {
  var coordinates = feature.geometry.coordinates;
  coords.push(L.LatLng(coordinates[1], coordinates[0])); // paramter's depending on your object
}
```

Then, use somewhat like:

```
// suppose, centerCoordinates is LatLng object as well
centerCoordinates.distanceTo(coords[0]);
```

link to `LngLat` object on Leaflet: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#latlng
link to `distanceTo` method on `LngLat`: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#latlng

Answer (score 0):

Since you're spawning `L.CircleMarker`s, and [`L.CircleMarker`s have a `getLatLng()` method](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#circlemarker-getlatlng), you can forego handling the coordinates yourself. Simply refer to the `CircleMarker` instance when calculating the distance, e.g.:

```
onEachFeature : function(feature,layer) {
  var distance = layer.getLatLng().distanceTo(centerPoint);
  layer.on('click',function(){
    layer.bindPopup("Distance to center: " + distance);
  });
}
```

Note that, in this case, the `distance` variable exists in a scope unique for each feature, so there's no need for [closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work). The calls to the `onEachFeature()` callback act as a closure here.